# MS SQL to MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

How would this stored procedure look like in MySQL? :

=========================================================================

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customer_Insert]
(
   @CustomerID int = NULL OUTPUT,
   @CustomerRef varchar(25),
   @Name varchar(64) = NULL,
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO [Customers]
(
    [CustomerRef],
    [Name]
)
VALUES
(
    @CustomerRef,
    @Name       
)

SELECT @CustomerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty straightforward, this should point you in the right direction. I have not executed it myself.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Customer_Insert
(OUT CustomerID INT, IN CustomerRef VARCHAR(25), IN Name VARCHAR(64))

BEGIN

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerRef, Name) VALUES (CustomerRef, Name);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO CustomerID;
END
```